# Why use group by 1, 2?

Tags: mysql, group

Here is the problem from leetcode.

```
Table: Sales

+--------------+---------+
| Column Name  | Type    |
+--------------+---------+
| sale_id      | int     |
| product_name | varchar |
| sale_date    | date    |
+--------------+---------+
sale_id is the primary key for this table.
Each row of this table contains the product name and the date it was sold.
 

Since table Sales was filled manually in the year 2000, product_name may contain leading and/or trailing white spaces, also they are case-insensitive.

Write an SQL query to report

product_name in lowercase without leading or trailing white spaces.
sale_date in the format ('YYYY-MM').
total the number of times the product was sold in this month.
Return the result table ordered by product_name in ascending order. In case of a tie, order it by sale_date in ascending order.
```

Most people wrote this in mysql:

```
select lower(trim(product_name)) as product_name, date_format (sale_date, '%Y-%m') as sale_date, count(*) as total
from sales
group by 1, 2
order by 1, 2;
```

I still don't get why 'group by 1, 2' has to be used instead of 'group by product_name, sale_date'. In mysql, group by is executed after select, right? The alias should be considered from the trim() etc, right?

Can someone help me clarify this? Thanks!

Comment: please add the *problem* as text not as link. We see this only if we have an account

Comment: I think the main reason is *The SQL standard does not allow you to use an alias in the GROUP BY clause whereas MySQL supports this.*

Comment: @Jens Thank you for the answer. So I can still use the alias in group by in mysql, right? That's why I am so confused... 

Comment: Yes for mysql it works. But not for other dbms

Comment: @Jens Thanks! I tried writing in this form and it works. The group by 1, 2 works similary as the below, right? 
group by lower(trim(product_name)), date_format (sale_date, '%Y-%m')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the same thing as a select alias and a column name is likely to get you into trouble.

The sale_date returned by the select is just a month; the sale_date column presumably has multiple potential values per month.  If you do:

```
select lower(trim(product_name)) as product_name, date_format (sale_date, '%Y-%m') as sale_date, count(*) as total
from sales
group by product_name, sale_date
order by 1, 2;
```

it is ambiguous as to whether you mean to group by sale_date the column or sale_date the alias.  mysql will assume you mean the column, which will *not* aggregate your results by month.

Either explicitly repeat the select expression:

```
group by lower(trim(product_name)), date_format(sale_date, '%Y-%m')
```

or use the shorthand that allows you to reference select columns:

```
group by 1, 2
```

Or distinguish between what you select and what is stored:

```
select lower(trim(product_name)) as display_product_name, date_format (sale_date, '%Y-%m') as sale_month, count(*) as total
from sales
group by display_product_name, sale_month
```

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, which finally solved my confusions. It seems like the ambiguity of group by the column or the alias is causing all the trouble, regardless of the order of execution of group by and select.